# No veo los valores que envio de parametos en WebView con Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter

Estoy utilizando WebView en una aplicación con flutter y se me ocurrió enviar parámetros por medio de la URL para capturarlos en mi sitio pero cuando reviso los datos me los muestra vacio.

El problema principal es cuando le paso los valores que provienen del SharedPreferences

Acá mi código de Dart en Flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class VisorTransforma extends StatefulWidget {
  const VisorTransforma({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VisorTransforma> createState() => _ViewVisorTransforma();
}

class _ViewVisorTransforma extends State<VisorTransforma> {

  String user = "";
  String pass = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    String url = "";
    obtenerdata();
    url = "user=$user&pass=$pass";


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(url),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: "https://miweb/login.php?" + url,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future obtenerdata() async {
    SharedPreferences data = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      user = (data.getString("login")) ?? "No obtenido";
      pass = (data.getString("pass")) ?? "No obtenido";      
    });    
  }
}
```

Luego en la página que apunto he colocado esto para visualizar que estoy capturando los parametros pero me aparecen vacios en ese alert.

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    var URLactual = window.location;
    alert(URLactual);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el `initialUrl` se crea solo la primera vez que el widget es insertado en el árbol de Widgets.

Como tu método `obtenerData` es asíncrono, la primera vez es nulo, luego que termina de cargar si haces un print de la URL verás que ya tiene info, pero el webview no actualizará ya que no es su URL inicial.

Modifiqué tu código, haciendo que carga la data asíncrona al inicio (en `initState`), luego de eso con una validación muestra un indicador circular cuando los datos aún no están cargados, luego de eso ya muestra el webview.

```dart
class _ViewVisorTransforma extends State<VisorTransforma> {
  String user = "";
  String pass = "";
  bool isDataLoaded = false;

  Future obtenerdata() async {
    SharedPreferences data = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isDataLoaded = true;
      user = (data.getString("login")) ?? "No obtenido";
      pass = (data.getString("pass")) ?? "No obtenido";
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    obtenerdata();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String url = "user=$user&pass=$pass";

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(url),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: isDataLoaded
            ? WebView(
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: "https://miweb/login.php?" + url,
              )
            : const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias! exactamente es como dices, me ha funcionado